# Error creating AWS lambda function using "sam build"

Tags: python, docker, ssl-certificate, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

When running `sam build --use-containers` to create an AWS python 3.8 lambda function that uses a downloaded library, I am getting an error:

`pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/d0/32/6c367f54699bd51961cf3e10299f6dee976f0f6813210052a4d8c2bd1d2b/pymemcache-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1108)')))`

I checked the certificate on https://files.pythonhosted.org, and the cert is marked as starting on 7/13/2020. it's currently 7/14/2020.

I see that I can set the trusted hosts option to hopefully avoid this, (similar to: [pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)), but when PIP is being run from within a container via a script Im not sure how to set it.

if looks like I can use an environment variable to set the PIP trusted hosts as well, but I am not sure how to set that in the docker image used by SAM

(running on a windows 10 system)

Comment: hows it going today?

Comment: still having the same problem.

Comment: from the lack of responses, I'm assuming that I'm the only one with this issue.

Comment: Seems like its a python problem within that docker instance, can you see if you can note/update the version of python its using? Also, I almost never use `--use-container`....takes way to long.

Comment: Since I am using some libraries that require local compiling, I needed it (as far as I can tell).   but... I added debug logging to the docker config and the problem went away.  No idea why.  it doesn't seem likely they are related, but hey, problem solved!

Comment: :) HAH! Sometimes thats how it goes. Lately, sam build hangs for me on building node  lambdas, I just restart.  Guess python's got the same issues.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user was attempting to use a newly created SSL certificate which had a starting datetime in the future. Once that datetime was in the past, things worked